# Web Browser Events using MsHTML.h

Tags: c++, c, browser, com, embed

I am using cwebpage integrated into my program. CWebpage information can be found here:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3365/Embed-an-HTML-control-in-your-own-window-using-pla

My question is regarding events. I currently have this setup to setup click events using get_anchors() in IHTMLDocument2. I then iterate over all of the elements to create a IDispatch in memory. This holds the event information. When an item is clicked, it sends a WM_NOTIFY to the window and then I can handle the event and parse out what I need to parse from the element that was selected. 
This all works fine until I run into a page in my software with close to 50,000 anchor tags in which we run out of memory since we hold the events in memory until the the page is destroyed.

Is there a simple way to obtain the clicked element without having to set an event for each individual element? Is it possible to set a click event at a document level and then find the element that tripped it? All I am trying to do is obtain the id of the element that is clicked.

What I've tried:
I tried to just use a WM_LBUTTONDOWN message read in our browser window and then use htmlDoc2->elementFromPoint() to simply get the information that I need from the element selected. This however does not work well if the page is zoomed or wraps.

Please note this programming is in C/C++, not javascript or vb.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML events "bubble" from child elements to parent elements.  So, you can simply assign a single `onClick` handler to the `IHTMLDocument2` itself, and then use the [`srcElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa703891(v=vs.85)) property of the [`IHTMLEventObj`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa703876(v%3Dvs.85)) object that is given to your handler every time on `onClick` event is fired by any child element on the page.  See [Understanding the Event Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ms533023(v=vs.94)).